# JQuery autocomplete with Node.JS express and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, mongoose

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favbar.png" />


<!-- JavaScript -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $("#search").autocomplete({

        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "/search",
              dataType: "jsonp",
              data: {
                 featureClass: "P",
                 style: "full",
                 maxRows: 12,
                 term: request.term
              },
              success: function( data ) {
                  response( $.map( data.results, function( item ) {
                       return {
                          label: item,
                          value: item
                       }
                  }));
             }
          });
       }

    });

  });
</script>
<script src="/stylesheets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/bootstrapui/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

   <input type="text" id="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search..." />


</head>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the node.js code:

```
app.post('/search', function (req, res){

   var regex = new RegExp(req.body.term);

   usermodel.aggregate({$match: { user: regex }}, function (err, users){

      if (err) throw err;

      var names = [];

      for (var nam in users) {

          names.push(users[nam].user);

      }

      var result = { results: names }

      res.json(result);

    });

});
```

This code doesn't work. I get perfectly the AJAX request, the problem is the Node.js response. I don't know if is the type of the response, or the way I send it. `names` in an array with all the results, and I send it like this `{ result: names }`. Maybe I should send only `res.json(result)`. In some examples use a GET request, and I use POST, should I change that? 
I use mongodb and mongoose for the database.

How can I do this? Thank's advance!

Comment: where is your response() function?

Comment: Where does it have to be? I don't know if you're talking about the node server or the front-end JS code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For autocomplete forms, i would recommend `twitter typeahead`. Very simple, easy to use and powerfull.

Some examples in: http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/examples/

Documentation and the code in: http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js

Comment: It was open sourced by twitter on feb 20. You do a lot with little code. I really like it. Nice it helped you.